# How find relationship of X on Y if both X and Y have trends?

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, causality, trend

I want to find an effect of X on Y. However, my Y and X are both have trends and seasonality. The first picture is my X and the second Y. The logic and academic results show that X should positively influence Y. However, when I will do regression I will have a negative coefficient (mainly due to opposing trends). Additionally< i have several different regressors which will help in the model. What can I do to find this effect. I guess the detrending should be done, but by which means? I heard that rolling window regression can help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature/origin of your data, a simple first way of detrending would  be to use a log-linear model for your time-series. 
For instance, for $Y$ the model would be

$log Y_t = y_t = \alpha + gt + \epsilon_t$.

where $\alpha+gt$ is your trend component and $\epsilon_t$ the cyclical component.
(Note that $t$ indexes time). 
Below is an example with data from the FED.

If you would take log-differences ($\Delta y_t = y_t - y_{t-1}$) you get something equivalent to a growth rate with a constant trend growth $g$ and the change in the cyclical component ($\Delta \epsilon_t$).

Important caveat with this approach is that there might appear to be a mean-reverting cyclical component, which is not there. 
Instead you could also use a Hodrick-Prescott filter.
Depending on the software you use there is also `decompose` in R which can help remove the trend and seasonal component.

I am sure others can add more useful suggestions as well.

#### Example GDP data US.

```
library(Quandl)
gdp <- Quandl("FRED/GDPC1",order="asc")          #data
gdp <- ts(gdp$Value,start=c(1947,1),frequency=4) #time-series: quarterly
gdp<-log(gdp)                                    #log-transform
gdp.dt<-ts(residuals(lm(gdp~index(gdp))), start=c(1947,1),frequency=4) #detrend
plot(gdp.dt)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This approach helps to detrend time series data in Y. Should I also use natural logarithm for my Xs, which have trend? Additionally, interpretation of the coeffcients will be changed using logarithms. I want to get coefficents what say in absolute terms that if X changes by 1 unit, Y changes by .. units, because some time my Y(not aggregated number as in the plot) is null. So it makes confusing in terms of interpretation using logarithms. I know that trend variable can be used as X2, but are there any other solutions to my problem_

Comment: Yes if there is a trend it is best to remove it, otherwise you end up with spurious regression ([e.g.](https://karlwhelan.com/Teaching/MA%20Econometrics/part4.pdf)). For the coefficients you can take the exponential function to transform them back I believe. But I am not 100% certain.